# Wrong number of arguments (2 for 0) for route setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes

I setup a typical route, controller, and view for a new "dispatch" page

Route:

```
get 'dispatch' => 'deliveries#dispatch', as: 'dispatch'
```

In DeliveriesController:

```
def dispatch
end
```

In "deliveries" folder, I added "dispatch.html.erb"

When I try to go to the link, I get the following error message:

```
Error message: Wrong number of arguments (2 for 0)
```

Better Errors highlights this code:

```
def self.action(name, klass = ActionDispatch::Request)
  middleware_stack.build(name.to_s) do |env|
    new.dispatch(name, klass.new(env))
  end
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dispatch` is an instance method in ActionController::Base. Changing your route/method name would be a first step in working out the exceptions cause.

Comment: yeah i lost like 3 hours with dispatch and send and they were both reserved methods.